# Can't find my error(s) in templated AVL tree

Tags: c++, syntax, avl-tree

I'm having trouble identifying syntax errors in my implementation of an AVL tree. I can't really tell whether I'm close or very far off (and it very well may be the latter), and I'm just looking for some general advice from anyone patient enough to take a look at this. Thank you very much if you actually do some looking, it means a lot that you would take your time to help. Please forgive the volume of code here, I just wanted to make sure all the context is present.

My testing has identified and highlighted some lines with vague messages. I've gone into the code below and put comments saying "/////Error Here/////" so it's easier to see. Many instances of _root are considered errors by the test program too, and I don't know why. I've included the source code and the header code.

Again, if you've taken the time to look at this, thank you so much. If not, I totally understand.

```
map.cpp

#include "map.h"
#include <map> // helper container for thread copying

template <typename KEY, typename T>
Map<KEY, T>::Map(){
    // create a dummy root node
    _root = new Elem;
    _root->left = _root;  // empty tree
    _root->right = 0;
    _root->rightThread = false;
    _size = 0;

}

// copy constructor
template <typename KEY, typename T>
Map<KEY, T>::Map(const Map<KEY,T> &v){
    // if empty tree
    if (v._root == v._root->left){
        _root = new Elem;
        _root->left = _root;  // empty tree
        _root->right = 0;
        _size = 0;
    } else {
        _root = new Elem;
        _root->left = _root;
        _root->right = 0;
        copyCode(_root->left, v._root->left); // to deep copy the tree without dummy nodes
        copyThread(_root, v._root); // to copy the threading; must pass dummy nodes to complete the threads
        _size = v._size;
    }
}

// construct a key-element map to rethread the new tree
// the map contains all nodes key values and their corresonding elem node address
// for furture lookup in setting up threads
template <typename KEY, typename T>
void Map<KEY, T>::addToMap(Elem* root, map<KEY, Elem*> &keyElemMap){
    if (root) {
        keyElemMap[root->key] = root;
        addToMap(root->left, keyElemMap);
        if (!root->rightThread)
            addToMap(root->right, keyElemMap);
    }
}

// common copy code for thread copying
template <typename KEY, typename T>
void Map<KEY, T>::copyThread(Elem* &newRoot, Elem* origRoot){
    // construct the key-element map for new and orig tree
    map<KEY, Elem*> newKeyElemMap;
    map<KEY, Elem*> origKeyElemMap;
    addToMap(newRoot->left, newKeyElemMap);
    addToMap(origRoot->left, origKeyElemMap);

    // start at the last element in the tree, which threads to root
    typename std::map<KEY, Elem*>::reverse_iterator it = origKeyElemMap.rbegin();
    newKeyElemMap[it->first] -> rightThread = true;
    newKeyElemMap[it->first] -> right = newRoot;

    // then thread the rest of the tree backwardly
    ++it;
    it != origKeyElemMap.rend()){
        if (it->second->rightThread){
            newKeyElemMap[it->first] -> rightThread = true;
            newKeyElemMap[it->first] -> right = newKeyElemMap[ origKeyElemMap[it->first]->right->key ];
        }
        ++it;
    }
}

// common copy code for deep copy a tree without copying threads
template <typename KEY, typename T>
void  Map<KEY,T>::copyCode(Elem* &newRoot, Elem* origRoot){
    if (origRoot == 0)
        newRoot = 0;
    else{
        newRoot = new Elem;
        newRoot->key = origRoot->key;
        newRoot->data = origRoot->data;
        newRoot->rightThread = origRoot->rightThread;
        copyCode(newRoot->left, origRoot->left);
        if (!origRoot->rightThread)
            copyCode(newRoot->right, origRoot->right);
    }
}

template <typename KEY, typename T>
void Map<KEY, T>::destructCode(Map<KEY, T>::Elem *& p) {
    if(p->left) {
     destructCode(p->left);
   }
   if(!p->rightThread) {
     destructCode(p->right);
   }
   delete p;
}

template <typename KEY, typename T>
Map<KEY, T>::~Map() {
    destructCode(_root->left);
    delete _root;
}

template <typename KEY, typename T>
Map<KEY, T>& Map<KEY, T>::operator=(const Map<KEY, T> &rhs) {
    if (rhs._root == rhs._root->left){
        _root = new Elem;
        _root->left = _root;  // empty tree
        _root->right = 0;
        _size = 0;
    } else {
        _root = new Elem;
        _root->left = _root;
        _root->right = 0;
        copyCode(_root->left, rhs._root->left);
        _size = rhs._size;
    }
    return *this;
}

template<typename KEY, typename T>
int Map<KEY, T>::height(Elem *node) {
    return node == 0 ? -1 : node->height;
}

int max(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}

template<typename KEY, typename T>
typename Map<KEY, T>::Elem* Map<KEY, T>::rotateRight(Elem* n) {
    Elem* m = n->left;
    Elem* p = m->right;

    // rotate
    m->right = n;
    n->left = p;

    // update height
    n->height = max(height(n->left), height(n->right)) + 1;
    m->height = max(height(m->left), height(m->right)) + 1;

    return m;
}

template<typename KEY, typename T>
typename Map<KEY, T>::Elem* Map<KEY, T>::rotateLeft(Elem* n) {
    Elem* m = n->right;
    Elem* p = m->left;

    // rotate
    m->left = n;
    n->right = p;

    // update height
    n->height = max(height(n->left), height(n->right)) + 1;
    m->height = max(height(m->left), height(m->right)) + 1;

    return m;
}

template<typename KEY, typename T>
typename Map<KEY, T>::Elem* Map<KEY, T>::doubleRotateRight(Elem* n) {
    // rotate right twice
    Elem* p = rotateRight(n);
    return rotateRight(p);
}

template<typename KEY, typename T>
typename Map<KEY, T>::Elem* Map<KEY, T>::doubleRotateLeft(Elem* n) {
    // and left twice
    Elem* p = rotateLeft(n);
    return rotateLeft(p);
}

template <typename KEY, typename T>
bool Map<KEY, T>::insert(KEY key, T info) {
    if (insert(_root->left, key, info, _root)){
    _size++;
        return true;
  }
    return false;
}

template <typename KEY, typename T>
bool Map<KEY, T>::insert(Map<KEY, T>::Elem *&cur, const KEY &key, const T &value, Map<KEY, T>::Elem* lastLeft) {
    if (cur == _root || cur == 0) { // map is empty
    cur = new Map<KEY, T>::Elem;
    cur->data = value;
    cur->left = 0;
    cur->right = lastLeft;
    cur->rightThread = true;
    return true;
  }

  if (value == cur->key){
    return false; // key exitsts already, don't insert
  }
  // insert at left
  if (value < cur->key)
    return insert( cur->left, key, value, cur);

  // insert at right
  if (!cur->rightThread){
    return insert(cur->right, key, value, lastLeft);
  } else {  // current's right is a thread; add a new node
    cur->rightThread = false;
    cur->right = new Map<KEY, T>::Elem;
    cur->right->data = value;
    cur->right->left = 0;
    cur->right->right = lastLeft;
      cur->right->rightThread = true;
    return true;
  }

  if (height(cur->left) - height(cur->right) == 2) { // calculate load factor
    if(key < cur->left->key) // outside case
      rotateRight(cur);
    else  // inside case
      doubleRotateRight(cur);
  }

  if (height(cur->left) - height(cur->right) == -2) { // calculate load factor
      if (key > cur->right->key) // outside case
        rotateLeft(cur);
      else  // inside case
        doubleRotateLeft(cur);
  }
}

template <typename KEY, typename T>
typename Map<KEY, T>::Elem& Map<KEY, T>::Iterator::operator*(){
    // fill in here
    return *_cur;
}

template <typename KEY, typename T>
typename Map<KEY, T>::Elem* Map<KEY, T>::Iterator::operator->(){
    // fill in here
    return _cur;
}

template <typename KEY, typename T>
int Map<KEY, T>::size() const{
    return _size;
}

template <typename KEY, typename T>
typename Map<KEY, T>::Iterator Map<KEY, T>::Iterator::operator++(int){
    // fill in here
    // in-order traversal
  Elem* p;
  p = this->_cur;
  while (!p->rightThread) {
    p = p->right;
  }
  while(p->right != _root) { /////Error Here/////
     if (!p->rightThread) {
       p = p->right;
             this._cur = p;
             return Map<KEY, T>::Iterator(p);
       while (p->left) {
         p = p->left;
       }
    } else {
       p = p->right;
             this->_cur = p;
             return Map<KEY, T>::Iterator(p);
    }
  }
  this._cur = _root; /////Error Here/////
  return _root;

    Elem *current, *parent;
    current = this._cur;

    return *this;
}
// output the structure of tree. The tree is output as "lying down"
// in which _root is the LEFT most Elem.
template <typename KEY, typename T>
void Map<KEY, T>::printTree(ostream& out, int level, Elem *p) const{
    int i;
    if (p) {
        if (p->right && !p->rightThread)
            printTree(out, level+1,p->right);
        for(i=0;i<level;i++) {
            out << "\t";
        }
        out << p->key << " " << p->data << '\n';
        printTree(out, level+1,p->left);
    }
}

// outputs information in tree in inorder traversal order
template <typename KEY, typename T>
ostream& Map<KEY, T>::dump(ostream& out) const{
    if ( _root == _root->left) {// tree empty
        return out;
    }
    printTree(out, 0, _root->left);   // print tree structure
    return out;
}


// outputs using overloaded << operator
template<typename KEY, typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Map<KEY, T>& v){
    v.dump(out);
    return out;
}
```

```
map.h

#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
// #include "map.cpp"
using namespace std;

template <typename KEY, typename T>
class Map{
private:
    struct Elem {
        KEY key;
        T data;
        Elem *left;
        Elem *right;
        bool rightThread;  // normal right child link or a thread link
        int height;
    };
    Elem *_root;  // a dummy root sentinel /////Error Here/////
    int _size;
public:
    // insert starter for other code and tests to use
    bool insert(KEY k, T t);
    // helper method for inserting into tree. takes care of insertion and balancing, returns true if successful
    bool insert(Elem *& root, const KEY &key, const T &data, Elem* lastLeft);

    // find height of node in the tree
    int height(Elem* node);

    // methods to do rotations
    Elem* rotateRight(Elem* n);
    Elem* rotateLeft(Elem* n);
    Elem* doubleRotateRight(Elem* n);
    Elem* doubleRotateLeft(Elem* n);

    // helper method for print tree
    void printTree(ostream& out, int level, Elem *p) const;

    // common code for deallocation
    void destructCode(Elem *& p);

    // common code for copy tree; not required.
    void copyCode(Elem* &newRoot, Elem* origRoot);

    // common code for deep copying threaded tree
    void addToMap(Elem* root, map<KEY, Elem*> &keyElemMap);
    void copyThread(Elem* &newRoot, Elem* origRoot);

public:
    // a simple Iterator, traverse the collection in one direction
    class Iterator{
    public:
        Iterator(){}
        explicit Iterator(Elem *cur):_cur(cur) {}
        Elem& operator*();
        Elem* operator->();
        Iterator operator++(int);
        bool operator==(Iterator it);
        bool operator!=(Iterator it);
    private:
        Elem* _cur;
    };
    Iterator begin() const;
    Iterator end() const;

    // constructs empty Map
    Map();

    // copy constructor
    Map(const Map &rhs);

    // destructor
    ~Map();

    // assignment operator
    Map& operator=(const Map &rhs);

    // return size of the Map
    int size() const;

    // return an iterator pointing to the end if the element is not found,
    // otherwise, return an iterator to the element
    Iterator find(KEY) const;

    // overloaded subscript operator
    T& operator[](KEY);

    // output the underlying BST
    ostream& dump(ostream& out) const;
};

template<typename KEY, typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Map<KEY, T>&);

#include "map.cpp"  // must include source file for template compilation
#endif
```

Comment: Terminology note: If you still have compiler errors you haven't started testing yet.

Comment: You have an error in copyThread `++it; it != origKeyElemMap.rend()){` it should be `++it; while (it != origKeyElemMap.rend()){`

Comment: Are you trying to compile map.cpp? Don't do that, it's not a real source file, just a fake header. And you don't compile header files.

Comment: Once I clean up the issues John raised, I reproduce no errors.